# Is there any programmer-oriented site for deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning

I browse and search some deep learning sites, but their contents always contain many mathematical notations or theories. That is normal, I know, but I can't turn them into real knowledge well if I wish to implement some "Hello,world." examples.

Is there any programmer-oriented sites for deep learning? None or as little mathematical notations and theories as possible and focusing implementation is the main direction.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Udacity course here https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning--ud730 to be really good for several reasons.

It uses Python, allowing you to focus more on the concepts then the coding.

The lectures break it down really well into small digestible concepts.

Every once and a while there are fun assignments to test your knowledge.

Using tensorflow to create neural networks is very easy, and also allows you to focus more on the concepts without having to worry about implementation of the actual neural network.

Comment: Thank you very much! I browse the course for a moment, it seems belong to me, I'll get to the class deeply, thanks again.